# IIS - How to specify a FastCGI TCP Transport Port

Tags: iis, fastcgi, fastcgi-mono-server

I am attempting to configure a FastCGI server on Windows 7 / IIS8 which needs to use TCP as it's protocol.

There is an option to use "TCP Protocol" when setting up the FastCGI application, but documentation is really scarce on how this works.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448989(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448989%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

How does one:

1. Specify a port to use
2. Find the port IIS wants to use when the process starts? (There doesn't appear to be any arguments when IIS spawns the process)